# What happens when there is no In-Sync-Replica and the leader node fails

Tags: apache-kafka

What happens when the broker that has a partition leader fails and there are no in-sync-replicas?

Is an outdated (not in-sync-replica) be made a partition leader? Or the topic becomes unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the partition leader isn't available due to some failure, the new leader is selected from the in-sync replicas.

But if no replica is in-sync it is possible to have an unclean leader election but you need to have this attribute enabled [unclean.leader.election.enable](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_unclean.leader.election.enable)
 and as you can imagine if this happens, any message that the in-sync replica did not have will be lost.